# Approximating ODE solution with polynomial function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

I am trying to decipher the method for generating non-linear frequency-modulated signals described [in this paper by A. W. Doerry](https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/1143324).  On page 5, there is an algorithm described that boils down to approximating a solution to the following differential equation
$$\omega'(t)=\frac{\omega'(0)}{W(\omega(t)-\omega(0))}$$
with the constraint of
$$\int_{-T/2}^{+T/2}\omega'(t)\,dt=\Omega.$$
A few easy to work with forms for $\omega(t)$ are given.  The one I'm focusing on is the polynomial form.
$$\tilde\omega(t)=\sum_{n=1}^N c_n\, t^{n-1} $$
The suggested iterative procedure for finding the polynomial (or whichever form) function fit is

1. Start with some initial $\tilde\omega'(t)$
2. Integrate $\tilde\omega'(t)$ to get $\tilde\omega(t)$
3. Adjust $\tilde\omega'(t)$ and $\tilde\omega(t)$ to meet $\Omega$ constraint
4. Calculate $W(\tilde\omega(t)-\tilde\omega(0))$ and the new $\tilde\omega'(t)$
5. Repeat steps 2-4 until the solution converges

I am paraphrasing some of this and simplifying the notation a bit.  Either way, I interpreted the above to mean start with some polynomial coefficients, fit the polynomial coefficients in $\tilde\omega'(t)$ to $\tilde\omega'(0)/W(\tilde\omega(t)-\tilde\omega(0))$ based on the coefficients you've got, adjust for constraints, and repeat.  This does not appear to work and I don't really see how it would.

Am I interpreting this wrong?  Is the algorithm in this paper referring to some well-known numerical differential equation solution approximation method?

**Edit**

$W(x)$ is a weighting function, specifically a sidelobe taper window.  Assume real and symmetric.  For example, a raised cosine window,
$$W(x) = 1+\frac{1-\alpha}{\alpha}\cos(Cx)$$
with $C$ being some constant to make the span work out right.  With $\alpha=25/46$ this is the ever-popular Hamming window.

Comment: What is $W$?Is it a function? What kind?

Comment: @Cesareo see edit

Comment: A couple remarks: 1. I guess wether this works or not depends heavily on the "adjust the parameters" part. 2. It looks a bit like Picard iteration. 3. Generally speaking a standard way to prove convergence of such a scheme is to show that the fixed-point operator is a contraction.

Comment: 4. Maybe I missunderstood the procedure but it looks to me like the scheme will not  give you a polynomial even if you start with one.

Comment: To be honest, I just don't understand at all what one is supposed to do in Step 3: adjust *in what way exactly?*. The paper itself seems to be equally vague on that point too, so I would say it is totally useless for actual coding. It is just a declaration that the author can do something successfully (which I sort of believe) but without any explanation how. If you really need to design and implement a working algorithm, we can discuss how one could approach the task, but guessing what the author might have had in mind when waving his hands like that is, probably, beyond our abilities...

Comment: @aquaticapetheory OK, that is one possible interpretation. Then I presume that after plugging in a polynomial, we do the least square approximation of the resulting function by a polynomial of degree $N-2$ on $[-T/2,T/2]$, which we then integrate to get the next $\omega$. Not sure why that is supposed to converge, but if you give me an example of $W$ and $T$ you are interested in, I can experiment with this when I have some free time and share my conclusions with you. :-)

Comment: @fedja I am actually having success interpreting the procedure as a modification of the Picard iteration as suggested by `maxmilgram`. I'm putting together some scripts to see it work and I was going to post the result if I get it but I think that's who'll get the bounty.  But if you want to give it a shot, you can use the $W$ I give in the edit. $T$ and $W$ are largely arbitrary but for a signal pulse 1e-3 and 1e+6, respectively, would work.

Comment: @maxmilgram I think your suggestion that it's a Picard iteration is correct.

Comment: @aquaticapetheory Yeah, give the bounty to maxmilgram :-). I just looked at what happens when $N=4$ (third degree polynomials), $W(x)=\frac 1{1+x^2}$ and $T=2$ (interval $[-1,1]$). In this case you can compute pretty much everything by hand and, if I don't mistake, for $\Omega$ from $0$ to about $12$ the iterations converge while for $\Omega$ above $12$ they diverge (both fixed points become repelling), so yeah, the method works occasionally but *it is not guaranteed to always work*. You are welcome to check my claim with your code. I'll post a few remarks later on how I would implement it.

Comment: So if I understand correctly you propose a rescaling $\omega\to \lambda\omega$ in step 3 and a least squares approximation im step 4 to remain in the polynomial space?

Comment: @maxmilgram Yes.  Step 4 is a refitting to f $\omega$ in polynomial form or whatever form it is in.  I'll put up a more detailed write-up if/when I get this working in a script hopefully later today.

Comment: @maxmilgram It's a Picard iteration as you suggested.  If you post an answer to that effect, I can give you the bounty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proposed scheme is a variation of a Picard iteration as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem).

However the proposed scheme deviates a little bit from a "standard" procedure especially when

1. You need to rescale the function
2. You need to approximate the solution to get back into the polinomial subspace.

Therefore to prove convergence we can directly apply the Banach fixed point theorem for a suitable fixed point operator and prove that this operator is a contraction.

Following the steps you proposed in the question and the comments we define

$$
\varphi(\nu)=\frac{\mu(\nu)\nu(0)}{W\left(\mu(\nu)\int_0^t\nu(s)ds\right)}
\quad\text{with}\\
\mu(\nu)=\frac{\Omega}{\int_{-T/2}^{T/2}\nu(s)ds} 
$$

Here $\nu$ plays the role of $\omega'$ and the operator $\varphi$ covers steps 1.-4. without the approximation. ($\mu$ incorporates the rescaling into the operator).

I played around a bit and although lengthy it seems doable to prove that

$$
\max|\varphi(\nu_0)-\varphi(\nu_1)|\leq C(\max(W),\min(W),\lambda_W,T,\Omega)\cdot \max|\nu_0-\nu_1|
$$

where $\lambda_W$ is the Lipschitz constant of $W$. (If you are interested in exact value of $C$ I found, I can post it here as well). This shows that for some choices of $\Omega,T,W$ the constant $C$ should be smaller than $1$ and the scheme does indeed converge.

Depending on your choice of polinomial approximation you will generally speaking get an additional constant $C_P$ that has to be taken into account namely

$$
\max|P(\varphi(\nu_0))-P(\varphi(\nu_1))|\leq C_P\cdot \max|\varphi(\nu_0)-\varphi(\nu_1)| \\
\leq C_P \cdot C(\max(W),\min(W),\lambda_W,T,\Omega)\cdot \max|\nu_0-\nu_1|
$$